# Grub Visual Error

Tags: grub

Grub start to look like that. Just visual, don't have any functional problem.
[image]

Comment: Did you manually change the font of the grub in order to make it better looking?

Comment: Actually don't...

Comment: It looks like the font is broken or some theming of grub is achieved. Can you open your terminal application, execute `cat /etc/default/grub`, edit your quesion above and add the output of the command?

Comment: I actually could resolve the problem by resetting the grub with Grub Customizer.

Comment: Haha, so you didn't manually change the font, the grub costumizer app did it!)) Can you answer your question with the **solution** you found and later accept it?

Comment: I don't know how to make it a "solution".

Comment: Add an answer and explain how you resolve your problem. After some time, click on the grey thickbox close to your answer to make it the one that is accepted